# Removing duplicates that appear more than once

Tags: c#, list, linq

Just practising a bit on linq and I am doing the usual remove items that are only duplicated more than once so in below example I have.

Word1 Word2 Word1

It should only print out word 2 Here is a https://dotnetfiddle.net/P47DGT is their an easy way of doing this with lambada better.

```
class Words {
    public string MyWords { get; set; }
}

public class Program    
{
    public static void Main()
{
  List<Words> _words = new List<Words>();
  _words.Add(new Words() { MyWords = "word1" });
  _words.Add(new Words() { MyWords = "word2" });
  _words.Add(new Words() { MyWords = "word1" });

   RemoveDuplicatesLinq(_words);
}   
    static void RemoveDuplicatesLinq(List<Words> _words) {
        List<Words> duplicatesRemoved = new List<Words>();
        duplicatesRemoved = _words.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(group => group.Key).ToList();  
        foreach (var item in duplicatesRemoved) {
            Console.Write("Words Left " + item.MyWords + "\r\n");
        }
    }       
}
```

It should just print me out the one occurrence Word2 but its not

Comment: You should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in `Words` class

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski surely theirs bound to a simpler way of doing it than having to override methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just group by `MyWords` and only filter the groups of length 1. Then you could flatten the groups into `IEnumerable<Words>` with [`System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1). Since you seem to want a list, we can add `ToList()` to convert the result to `List<Words>`.

```
List<Words> duplicatesRemoved = _words
            .GroupBy(x => x.MyWords)
            .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
            .SelectMany(group => group)
            .ToList();

foreach (var item in duplicatesRemoved)
{
    Console.Write("Words Left " + item.MyWords + "\r\n");
}
```

Which Outputs:

```
Words Left word2
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible option here can be a wrapping `MyWords` property into anonymous type (they are compared by property values, not by the reference equality), then select groups with count equals `1`

```cs
var duplicatesRemoved = _words.GroupBy(x => new { x.MyWords })
    .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
    .Select(group => group.Key).ToList();

foreach (var item in duplicatesRemoved)
{
    Console.Write("Words Left " + item.MyWords + "\r\n");
}
```

In your code `group.Count() > 1` condition means select groups with duplicates, but actually you'll need the opposite.

Another option is to group the source list by `MyWords` property, get the groups with count equals 1 and then select the first item from these groups (because there is only one item in every group after `Where` clause)

```cs
var duplicatesRemoved = _words.GroupBy(x => x.MyWords)
    .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Would their be a way of doing it without linq

Comment: @rogue39nin manage a loop and go through the source collection or use a hashset. However, the linq solution seems to be a simplest here